# Agregar checked al valor de input mediante php

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, get

Como puedo agregar un checked al valor de un input mediante un get e el index. Mi input es el siguiente:

```
<input type="radio" id="entret" name="categories" value="entret">
```

En mi pagina principal tengo este link que me enviara a la pagina php con el contenido que requiero filtrar.

```
<a href="directorio.php?categoria=entretenimiento">
```

Y mando a llamar en el documento php con este código, el cual me funciona hasta ahi.

```
if($_GET['categoria']=="entretenimiento")
```

Pero requiero agregar al valor del input un checked (`<input type="radio" id="entret" name="categories" value="entret" checked>`), pero no se como hacerlo, solo en JS, el cual seria con el código siguiente:

```
$('#entret').prop("checked", false);
```

¿En el caso de php como podría agregar ese valor para que sea seleccionado al dar clic al link?

Comment: Léete [ask] y como hacer un [example].  De paso haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio.  En tu pregunta no sabemos como estás generando ese input ni cuando. Nos falta contexto. Procura poner todo el código necesario para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta tantas veces lo necesites para agregar la información que falta. Encontrarás el enlace a [edit] en el pie de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que para recoger el valor de ese check lo que se tendría que hacer es usar el método post de la siguiente manera.

```
if(isset($_POST['opcion1'])){
echo "checked value1"."<br>";
} if(isset($_POST['opcion2'])){
   echo "checked value2"; } ?>
```

Con esto se pretende tomar el valor de ese check y manipularlo.
Obiamente ya definiendo el formulario en php con html.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" >
<input type="checkbox" name="opcion1" value="value1"> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="opcion2" value="value2"> Option 2
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Con eso se puede hacer, sin embargo hay más formas, solo depende de cual se gusta usar.